# Fail-safe object moving AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Im trying to make a simple object move from its original position to one of the corners in which direction the mouse is being moved. But its a bit trickier, because I need the mouse to travel some distance in one of the directions before moving the object in that corners, in which the mouse is being moved ( to be sure that we didnt accidentally moved the mouse/object ).

I was thinking that I have to save the starting point when the mouse has been pressedDown, and after that to check when it(the mouse) has moved XX pixels in one of the directions and then if moved above some point (in which we are sure that it is not a random movement) move the object to one of the corners. But .... I cant quite figure it out howe to be done by code.

To show more clearly the above Ill explain it with this picture
[image]

So the **Gray Box** is our object.

The **Arrows** are the directions in which we can move the box.

The **Green line** is the distance that we need to move our mouse (while it is pressedDown)so the object moves in one of the directions./in this example 50px/

Lets assume we clicked the **Grey Box** in the upper right corner(where the **filled green circle** is), so if we want to move the box to the LEFT, we need at least to move the mouse(while it is still pressedDown) to the position where the **left hollow green circle** is. And if we want to move the object to the RIGHT, we need to move the mouse to the **right hollow green circle**, before the **Grey Box** goes in that corner.

The RED and BLUE circles are just different scenarios, representing different points in which we have clicked the BOX and where we need to move the mouse, so the BOX moves.

:) Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Post the code you've tried.   You're correct in that you just need to store the mouse point on `MOUSE_DOWN` and listen either on `ENTER_FRAME` or `MOUSE_MOVE` (better) and check there if the current mouse position has moved far enough from the mouse down point to be considered a move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
var grayBox:Sprite; //let's say this is your gray square or whatever you're clicking
grayBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);


var mouseDownPoint:Point = new Point(); //the point to capture on mouse down to compare against
var currentObject:DisplayObject; //to store the current object on mouse down
var threshold:int = 50; //how far in pixels the mouse needs to move before you count it as a move
var didItMove:Boolean = false; //stores whether the current click was a move

function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    mouseDownPoint.x = e.stageX;
    mouseDownPoint.y = e.stageY;
    currentObject = e.currentTarget as DisplayObject;
    didItMove = false; //reset this
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHanlder, false, 0, true); //listen to mouse move until mouse up
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
}

function mouseMoveHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (Math.abs(e.stageX - mouseDownPoint.x) > threshold || Math.abs(e.stageY - mouseDownPoint.y) > threshold) {
        //moved far enough 
        didItMove = true;
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler); //remove listener
    }
}

function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(stage.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE)) stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler); //remove listener if still around
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler); //remove the mouse up listener from the stage
    if (didItMove) {
        //do something

        //use currentObject 

        if(e.stageX > mouseDownPoint.x:
            if(e.stageY > mouseDownPoint.y){
                //bottom right corner
            }else {
                //top right corner
            }
        }else{
            if(e.stageY > mouseDownPoint.y){
                //bottom left corner
            }else {
                //top left corner
            }
        }
    }

    currentObject = null; //free the var so it's hanging around in memory
}
```

Comment: well I didnt dream of this to happen so soon :D. Usually it takes 3 to 4 days with alot of help and alot of trying and failing to get something working like I intended it to be. Thanks a lot @LDMS it works like a charm.

Comment: Hmmm ... Now I noticed that it only works if you let go the mouse button when inside the **object**. If  you click the **Object** and move above that needed distance, but outside the **object** boundaries
it doesnt trigger. Any clues on how to solve this problem ?

(im trying with e.stageX e.stageY instead of e.localX e.localY but still doesnt work)

Comment: Add the mouse up listener to the stage

Comment: I tried that but then it doesnt matter in what direction you move the mouse, the object will always move to the Right edge( if we can only move it left or right), because **e.localX** is always >bigger> then **mouseDownPoint.x** in the mouseUpHandler function.

Comment: I have uploaded the code here [MouseProblem](http://wonderfl.net/c/sDhp) ( you write your code there and it automatically shows the result in the browser so one can see what is going on ). If want to see what is going on

Comment: Right, that's because on the mouse up localY is relative to the stage, which is different than on the mouse down (relative to the square).  Change all instances of localY/X to stageY/X and it should work.

Comment: yep that almost worked :D because again when you go beyond the bounderies of the object is stops counting. So i had to add the MOUSE_MOVE event to the stage and not to the object, and add another boolean **wasObjectPressed** and make it true only when i press the object. But your advice brought me to it.

Comment: can I ask if lets say i have 10-20 elements and i have to do this verification whenever i click one of them ? how would you do it ? youll give every element a name and when clicked youll store its name, and if we have traveled the distance then move this object(with the name) ? or is there a better way/ you would do it different

Comment: haha yes,  so often I forget about mouse move needing to be on the stage.  Not sure why you would need a `wasObjectPressed` var though in addition to `didItMove`?

Comment: If you're not supporting multitouch, you can just keep adding the same mouse down handler to everything and it should work just fine.   eg `obj1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);`  ... `obj2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler)` ... `obj3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler)` ...   If you need MULTITOUCH though, then it gets much more complicated.

Comment: because.... im not very smart :D. yea i see it now -> i just have to set it to false in the end of the **mouseUpHandler** function

Comment: Its ment to be simple SINGLETOUCH. hmmm now I'm trying what you suggested but since **MOUSE_UP** is added to the stage there is no way 
i can know which element to move unless I save its name or something from it so i can identify what to move. cause now i only move the last created element that was putted on stage

Comment: you could use `e.target`, it will either be the object clicked, or a child of it.  If set `obj.mouseChildren = false` it will for sure then be the same object as the mouse down.

Comment: well Im doing what you are saying and it gives me **Error: Error #2071: The Stage class does not implement this property or method.** ( i still think its because _mouseUpHandler_ is applied to the stage and not to an element so it doesnt know which element to move.
I`ve uploaded the code to this link  [mouseOnMultipleObjects](http://wonderfl.net/c/ex2K)(it doesnt give you the error but ... because there is no output window but it doesnt work)

Comment: Right, I suppose if the mouse isn't actually over the item in question when you release it, the target will be stage.   Yes, to reliably do this you'll need to store the current object on mouse down (just like we store the current mouse point).

Comment: yep : ). If i stumble upon a new problem can I ask here, and hope that you would read it, and if you have time to assist in this horrific "project"